# Docker-Mongodb - How to connect to the mongo image in local(windows)

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to connect to my docker mongo image, I installed mongodb in local, and added the mongodb bin path to windows path environment variable. And I am doing below steps

```
cd <docker-location>

docker login

docker ps
```

> -- to check already mongo running

```
docker pull myrepo/mymongo-image:1.0
docker run -p 27017:27017 -d --net=host --name=mytestDB myrepo/mymongo-image:1.0

docker logs mytestDB
```

Output: MongoDB starting : pid=6 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=moby
    docker ps
Output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
34598734598        myrepo/mymongo-image:1.0   "/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/"   12 hours ago        Up About a minute                       mytestDB
```

start mongo in local:

```
mongo --port 27017
```

But I am getting error like this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2016-10-13T20:04:12.273+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2016-10-13T20:04:12.277+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:226:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Please let me know where I did mistake.

Comment: when you run "docker ps" your ports column is empty ...is this a copy paste error, or is that how it actually displays? Could your localhost not have that port open somehow?

Comment: I also observed that, it not showing port in 'docker ps' command.

Answer (score 7):

I got solution, I like to share it.

`'--noauth --bind_ip=0.0.0.0'` options are missed in my commands.

This is the blog bring me out.

[Tutorial: Setting up MongoDB Image Instance with Docker Toolbox](http://codehangar.io/mongodb-image-instance-with-docker-toolbox-tutorial/)

Comment: the link which @sun mention above help me alot

Answer (score 0):

if you have already installed docker-toolbox and you have created an image but unable to visualize your mongodb database through robo3t

for this illustration i created my image with command

```
docker run --name blogA -p 27017:27017 -d mongo
```

Note: since 27017  is port for mongodb

> Open up VirtualBox. Right click the "Default" machine.
>
> Select settings from the menu.
>
> Choose the Network tab in the settings menu.
>
> Choose port forwarding at the bottom of the network option.
>
> Click the plus icon to the right of the port forwarding menu.
>
> Make the new entry with the name mongo.
>
> Protocol should be TCP. Host and Guest IP can be left empty.
>
> Set the host port to the port you make use in creating your
>
> image I made use of port 27017. Set the guest port to 27017.
>
> install robo3t from http://robomongo.org/download.html
>
> click icon below file tab to create a new connection
>
> Choose to create a new connection.
>
> Name your connection and set the address to localhost and port to the port you set your Host port too in VirtualBox, in my case is 27017